# How do I preserve the file selected for a file type input across a request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an `input type="file"` tag in some views. When I submit the form, if there is a validation problem and my controller action returns the same/view model but with validation errors, the file selected for the file input is cleared. How can I preserve this selected file?

Comment: Is that not the default of ASP.Net FileUpload control as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually get the same behavior with `input type="password"` tags. It is a security measure in browsers used to help protect users from malicious servers, who might try to gain access to a user's private sensitive files by pre-populating them in a file upload field.

If the file is invalid, why would you want to preserve it?

**Reply to comment**

If that is the case, you should be able to handle the other field validations on the client without doing a full postback. This would preserve the users' file upload entry since the page would not be re-rendered by the server after validation errors are discovered.

Comment: The file is part of a larger post, other parts of which may be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible for security reasons. You cannot set the `value` attribute of a file input field and this is the reason why you cannot populate it after postback.